# How to avoid finding ancestors with Protractor cssContainingText locator

Tags: protractor

I have a test that needs to determine if a span exists; I want to locate the span by the text it contains for scaleability. I tried to use `element(by.cssContainingText('*', 'Test Text'))` but it turns out that in addition to matching the span, it also matches every ancestor it has. How do I avoid this (`.last` will not work as there are multiple spans that contain the text and I want to locate the first one)?

Preferably, I want a locator that works *exactly* like `buttonText` except without the button restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the first element on the page that has the text that you provide:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "test text")]'));
```

If you wanted to get all of the elements, just tack on a .all after element.

Comment: The tag might change since right now it's a span via {{}} and it might later be turned into a ng-bind directive on the parent element. The only thing that won't change is the text.

Comment: So you want to get the first element on a page that has that text without knowing what the text will be in? Just making sure I know exactly before I answer again.

Comment: Correct. Ideally without creating a custom locator or filtering already found elements with `.filter`.

Comment: Revised answer.